# C++ class casting

Tags: class, object, casting

Guys I am trying to create an object that can instantiate the other types that inherit it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Animal {

    public:
    
        char *nome;
    
        Animal (char *nome) {
            this->nome = nome;
        }

};

class Cachorro : public Animal {
    
    public:
    
        bool enterraOsso;
    
        Cachorro (char* nome, bool enterraOsso) : Animal(nome) {
            this->enterraOsso = enterraOsso;
        }

};

class Passaro : public Animal {

    public:
    
        bool voar;
    
        Passaro (char* nome, bool voar) : Animal(nome) {
            this->voar = voar;
        }

};

int main() {

    Animal *animal;
   
    animal = new Cachorro("Scooby", true);
    std::cout << animal->nome << ", " << animal->enterraOsso << std::endl;
   
    animal = new Passaro("Piopio", false);
    std::cout << animal->nome << ", " << animal->voar << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to access the subclass attributes from the superclass also.

I don't know if this is a cast or polymorphism, in Java I know it is possible, but can't do it in C++.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Please ask in English or post to [pt.so] instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English - this is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site!

Answer (score 0):

You can, it is bad design though for a Base class to know about its children:

```
int main() {

    Animal *animal;

    animal = new Cachorro("Scooby", true);
    Cachorro * c = reinterpret_cast<Cachorro*>(animal);
    std::cout << animal->nome << ", " << c->enterraOsso << std::endl;


    animal = new Passaro("Piopio", false);
    Passaro * p = reinterpret_cast<Passaro*>(animal);
    std::cout << animal->nome << ", " << p->voar << std::endl;

}
```